# 'Next Page' on Profile loses CSS

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design, rendering

Occasionally, I'll want to look through my older questions or answers from my profile page. There have been a few instances (including just a moment ago) when clicking on the next page in my list of questions will cause the page to render without CSS - a right ugly mess.

I believe this also happens when I change the sort order (votes, views, etc).

This is the only page I've ever seen lose it's CSS on SO.

---

**Edit:** It just happened again when I tried to order my questions by views. The page now shows only the questions section, with no CSS. The address shown has also changed to "https://stackoverflow.com/api/userquestions.html?userid=1588&page=1&pagesize=10&sort=views". I still have the tab open, and have Firebug installed. I've uploaded a cropped image of the tab.

[image]

Comment: closing as norepro since the steps you describe, I can't repro. There is a very narrow way (closing a question) to make this happen in Firefox 3.5 due to a bug in that browser.

Comment: This happens to me when the javascript file gets blocked.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced this at work where many things are blocked (ads, external email, lots of websites, etc.). Also I can only use IE at work. It is a localized javascript issue. I can see all the content of the page with just basic html formatting. The most common place I see it is trying go to "page 2" of my questions or answers. Are you running any no-script type plugin's? You may want to reset your browser once in a while to help keep things clean.

Answer (score 0):

You might be running into dynamic request throttling.

What browser?

There's a serious JavaScript-related bug in Firefox (latest and greatest at the time of my posting) which will sometimes cause it to force-reload EVERY element on the page from the server even when it shouldn't. We've reproed this locally as well (and not-reproed it in Chrome under the same circumstances).

Comment: Hey Jeff, sorry for not following up on this sooner but I don't check meta that often. I'm running FF 3.0 (3.0.13 atm). I'm open to the possibility that this is due to one of my extensions, but I had enough difficulty with the repro even with everything enabled.